# Promise reject error - Unhandled rejection Error: closed

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I use the following code to check some app port currenlty its working but I got error in the third else statement

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Port is not open
```

How can I handle that ?
I use bluebird

```
checkPortStatus: function(port, host){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    portscanner.checkPortStatus(port, host, function(error, status) {
      if(error)
        reject(error);
      else if(status === 'open')
        resolve(status);
      else
        reject(new Error('Port is not open'));
    });
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, you need to handle rejected promises, for instance using a [`.catch()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html):

```
obj.checkPortStatus(port, host).then((status) => {
  ...
}).catch((err) => {
  // handle the error here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes of the code calling checkPortStatus cause the unhandled exception.

That code might look like

```
somePromiseFunction()
.then(checkPortStatus(port, host))
.then(someOtherPromiseFunction())
```

It would (minimally) "handle" the exception if it looked more like

```
somePromiseFunction()
.then(checkPortStatus(port, host))
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error.message);
})
.then(someOtherPromiseFunction()
```

There's trouble in your code in this aspect: When using `resolve` and `reject`, it's also necessary to use `return`. So instead of `resolve()`, use `return resolve()`; same with `reject`.

A side note, in case it helps: Once you add the `return`s I mention, each of the `else` statements in your code is immediately preceded by a `return`. You can delete the `else` statements.

Good luck!

Comment: It's not _necessary_ to add a `return` (see [the example code](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/new-promise.html)), but I do agree that it would make the code a bit more structured.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for sharing. That might have been different in the past; I appreciate the info. Knowing that, I'll clean up my code a bit.